# Relative interior of $\{ u \in L^2(\Omega) : u \geq 0 \text{ a.e.}\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

What is the relative interior of $P:=\{ u \in L^2(\Omega) : u \geq 0 \text{ a.e.}\}$?

It seems to me it should be $\{ u \in L^2(\Omega) : u > 0 \text{ a.e.}\}$ but I cant prove it since it seems to me hard to see what the affine hull of $P$ should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affine hull of $P$ is $L^{2}(\Omega)$. (Use $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$). Hence the relative interior is same as the interior in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ which is empty!

Note that $f \in P$ implies $fI_{{A_{n}}^{c}}- I_{A_{n}}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ if $A_n$ is a sequence of  sets of finite positive measure  whose measures tend to $0$ (assuming that such  sets exists; they exist in any non-atomic space). Hence $P$ has no interior.

Comment: This is only true if the measure is not purely atomic. In the purely atomic situation, $P$ has a non-empty interior.

Comment: $P$ has empty interior for counting measure on $\mathbb N$

Comment: Yes, of course. But it has an interior for the counting measure on a finite set.